API 34 | Google Play Request
Can anyone help me with my React Native Expo app? I need to set the configuration to target API level 34 (Android 14). I've set the following in the app.json under the android section:
"targetSdkVersion": 34,
"compileSdkVersion": 34

And I also added this in the expo-build-properties section:
"expo-build-properties": {
  "android": {
    "usesCleartextTraffic": true,
    "targetSdkVersion": 34,
    "compileSdkVersion": 34
  },
  "ios": {
    "deploymentTarget": "13.4"
  }
}

However, when I build the app, it still targets API level 33. I've tried updating my packages and dependencies, but after doing so, I can no longer run the project (npx expo run:android).
Can anyone help me resolve this issue?
